# Postgis ST_DWithin match a certain radius AND points on the right

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, rgeo

I'm using postgis 9.1 and rgeo to develop an map application.

One of the features implies that I find all points that are XXX kms from the current point, and are also on the right of the Point.

I tried with the following query:

`Environment.where{ st_dwithin(location, factory.point(170.0, 0), 300000 ) }.where('ST_X(location::geometry) > 170')`

The corresponding SQL for the query:
[EDITED]

`SELECT "environments".* FROM "environments" WHERE (st_dwithin("environments"."location", ST_PointFromText('POINT(170 0)', 4326), 300000)) AND (ST_X(location::geometry) > 170 );`

Here I hardcoded the point to be in the 170 longitude.

The problem with this is that I can't match points in the [-170,-180] longitudes.

Is there a way to solve this using only postgis functions?

[EDIT] This is a around the world problem with postgis. In this application I'm allowed only to find points to the right and in a certain range.. I can't find a solution with pure SQL...

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not hard-code data in a binary format. I do not think anybody on SO can read HEXEWKB. Can you please edit to regular coordinates?

Comment: Do you realize that you are effectively using Cartesian distance units in degrees?

Comment: Patrick I'm using a ruby library, rgeo, which translated to the binary format you see. But this is the same for: SELECT "environments".* FROM "environments"  WHERE (st_dwithin("environments"."location", ST_PointFromText('POINT(-170 0)', 4326), 150000));

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `geography` type rather than the `geometry` type.

- [What are the pros and cons of PostGIS geography and geometry types?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/6681/1872)
- [Introduction to PostGIS: Section 17: Geography](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/geography.html)

Comment: Thanks Mike. I'm using geography type in the column location from relation Environment. The postgis function ST_X only works with geometries.

Comment: use `ST_X(geog::geometry)` or `ST_AsLatLonText(geog::geometry)` to get coordinate data from geography types.